# Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/app/package.json'

Tags: reactjs, node.js, docker, npm

I was trying to run the application but shows EACCES error

code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /app/package.json
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: Could not read package.json: Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/app/package.json'
npm ERR!  [Error: Could not read package.json: Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/app/package.json'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: '/app/package.json'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

I tried everything as I could to solve this problem but so far not able to resolve this issue. Can someone help me solve this problem? Thanks and here is my code

```js
# set the base image to create the image for react app
FROM node:20-alpine3.18

# create a user with permissions to run the app
# -S -> create a system user
# -G -> add the user to a group
# This is done to avoid running the app as root
# If the app is run as root, any vulnerability in the app can be exploited to gain access to the host system
# It's a good practice to run the app as a non-root user
RUN addgroup app && adduser -S -G app app

# set the user to run the app
USER app

# set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# copy package.json and package-lock.json to the working directory
# This is done before copying the rest of the files to take advantage of Docker’s cache
# If the package.json and package-lock.json files haven’t changed, Docker will use the cached dependencies
COPY package*.json ./

# sometimes the ownership of the files in the working directory is changed to root
# and thus the app can't access the files and throws an error -> EACCES: permission denied
# to avoid this, change the ownership of the files to the root user
USER root

# change the ownership of the /app directory to the app user
# chown -R <user>:<group> <directory>
# chown command changes the user and/or group ownership of for given file.
RUN chown -R app:app .

# change the user back to the app user
USER app

# install dependencies
RUN npm install

# copy the rest of the files to the working directory
COPY . .

# expose port 5173 to tell Docker that the container listens on the specified network ports at runtime
EXPOSE 5173

# command to run the app
CMD npm run dev
```

Comment: How are you running the container?  (Do you have a volume mount that hides everything in the image?)  I'd argue the files usually _should_ be owned by root (don't switch to `USER app` until the end of the Dockerfile), but they should also be world-readable, so you shouldn't have permission problems just running the application.